# color, insert link and insert image popup not showing in wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wysihtml5

Hey every one I have following issues `color`, `insert link` and `insert image` popup not showing in `wysihtml5`. when i check the inspect element the div insert image button after update and in inspect element

```
<div class="bootstrap-wysihtml5-insert-image-modal modal fade in" style="display: none;">
```

and this is automatically add when i click the button `style="display: none;"`

this have `modal` class and modal class inherit from bootstrap. modal class have two properties

```
overflow: 'hidden'; 
display : none;
```

when i remove this property from inspect element popup is showing other wise popup not showing what should i do please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow: 'hidden';` part is wrong. Also remove `display: none;` as it is already done programmatically. Finally your code should be:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: problem is overflow: hidden and display are in modal class. modal class are inherit from bootstrap.css so how can i change the property

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the modal does not show is because `display: none` will make it invisible. `overflow: hidden` may also hide the content if the width and height of the modal are now set accordingly.

To show the modal you should apply `display: block` or something similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this..

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

and remove the *display:none*